# url-encode body of http request

Tags: java, http, servlets, urlencode

Can someone explain to me what is actually the need to Url-encode
data sent in the body part of http requests when using

```
      content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

By "the need", do you mean "the purpose"?

If you're after the purple - it is simply there to tell the server what to expect: URL-encoded key=value pairs. It also allows the server to know what is *not* coming its way - the likes of multipart/form-data!
This allows the server to unambiguously know how to read incoming data.

The data is sent as one header (this is also why it has a size limit). As such, you definitely want to avoid stuff like: newlines, colons. In addition to this, you definitely want to escape = in data, so that it doesn't mess with the key=value structure. You also want to escape & for the same reason. URL-encoding does all that - so it only makes sense that whoever designed the HTTP protocol went for it!

Comment: I can understand why the url end the query string attached to it have to be url-encoded , but posting data means that data get sent as the body part of the message , so why url-encoding it ?.

Comment: The data is sent as one header (this is also why it has a size limit). As such, you definitely want to avoid stuff like: newlines, colons. In addition to this, you definitely want to escape = in data, so that it doesn't mess with the key=value structure. You also want to escape & for the same reason. URL-encoding does all that - so it only makes sense that whoever designed the HTTP protocol went for it!

Comment: @user1800246 - You should edit your answer to contain your comment above.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to send data to the server in a POST request; URL Encoded data is just one of several possible formats.

The client and server have to agree on the format of data in the POST body. URL Form encoded data is the easiest to use because of its universal support. Browsers support it natively. Every programming language allows you to read url encoded post parameters using a familiar syntax.

But of course, there is no need to use url form encoded. You can as easily send json or xml encoded POST body. As long as the client and server are in sync, you can even create a totally different encoding and use it.

Comment: I understand that but I wonder why it is used url-encoding , which encodes a great variety of characters while the only characters that we have really the need to encode are '=' and '&' .